# How do I compare a date column with a date and add a text column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
id      date
1       2019-09-28
2       NaT
3       2017-09-28
```

I want to compare the date column to a date: 2018-09-28.  Then add a column status that adds a string 'Greater' or 'Less' based on the comparison.  So the output would be something like this:

```
id      date          status
1       2019-09-28    Greater
2       NaT
3       2017-09-28    Less
```

Comment: What about when it's equal to?

Comment: Just put greater if its equal to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Pandas `datetime` series, you can compare values with a string:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['status'] = np.where(df['date'] >= '2018-09-28', 'Greater', 'Less')
df.loc[df['date'].isnull(), 'status'] = ''

print(df)

   id       date   status
0   1 2019-09-28  Greater
1   2        NaT         
2   3 2017-09-28     Less
```